# are Classes and Methods in the Javax package Static or not?

Tags: java

I want to ask if the Methods and Classes in javax package are Static or not? like JOptionPane for example.
"i can use it without constructed object from the JOptionPane Class "

Comment: You can use *what*? Some methods will be static, some won't...

Comment: [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) will tell you ;)

Comment: Are you really interested in whole `javax` package or only in [tag:swing]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package javax is a very big package with many sub packages and classes.
Certainly there are static methods and non static methods, same for classes.

Check the official documentation to see wich methods are static and wich aren't http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/

In particular the class JOptionPane is a non static class with both static and non static methods http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?javax/swing/JOptionPane.html

For example

```
public static Frame getRootFrame()
                      throws HeadlessException
```

and

```
public void setUI(OptionPaneUI ui)
```